# Path to subfolder of current directory

Tags: joomla

Using Joomla I'm on a page called `site` with the URL `https://my.domain.tld/some/path/to/the/site`. I want to create a link `<a>` on that page to `link` with it's URL `https://my.domain.tld/some/path/to/the/site/link` while the link needs to be relative because `site` is a dynamically generated page.

I am confused... Using `link` in `href` the URL is `https://my.domain.tld/some/path/to/the/link`, the same happens with `./link`. What am I missing?

What would I write in the `href` part to get an URL to `link` relative to the current page `site`?

Comment: Have you looked at this ? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: No, I didn't know that by now but is there a solution without JS? What if a user has disabled JS?

Comment: I'm not sure in that case.

Comment: When you are having questions regarding your Joomla site, please ask on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.